# Passing selected rows from one jsp table to another jsp table

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my jsp(index.jsp) I display some items in table with `checkbox` at the beginning of each row. If user check a row and click the confirm button it goes to other jsp(**second.jsp)** where I need to display all the rows which are checked in **index.jsp**.

my table looks like this and assume i enclosed table in form tag.

```
<form:form method="post" action="/somereq" modelattribute="transferInvoice">
            <table id="assets-tbl" border="1"
                class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped"
    <tbody id="assets-tbl-body" >
                    <c:forEach items="${transferinvoice}" var="invoice" varStatus="status">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id="cartcheckbox" class="case" type="checkbox" name="case" value="${invoice}"/></td>
                            <td>${invoice.some}</td>
                            <td>${invoice.num}</td>
                            <td>${invoice.name}</td>
                            <td>${invoice.loca}</td>
                            <td>${invoice.time}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
```

Can any one help me?

I tried this but some how able to fetch the selected rows into controller but how to pass these values to another jsp as java bean type unless can't able to parse the results in second.jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value = "somereq", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView transferInvoiceConfirm(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
            Model model = new ExtendedModelMap();


    String[] checkeditems =request.getParameterValues("caseob");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(checkeditems);
    List<beantype> invoicelist = new ArrayList<beantype>(list);
    model.addAttribute("invoiceList", list);
    return new ModelAndView("asset/secondform", model.asMap());

}
```

and in the second jsp, I am displaying the checked items in table as

```
<c:forEach items="${invoiceList}" var="invoice" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${invoice.name}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.code}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.model}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.loc}</td>
                        <td>${invoice.date}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

Somehow i feel, i am doing wrong things. Can any one please help to fix this issue?

Comment: How is the "goes to other jsp" action performed?

Comment: I was thinking to enclose this table in form. Might read all the checkbox selected rows in controller and read them in other jsp.

Comment: Can any one help me still i am unable to achieve my task.

Comment: You still didn't include the code that submits the data to `somereq`. You'd benefit from slicing your problems into discrete parts that should be all covered in other SO questions already: how to submit form to the back-end, how to read form data from an `HttpServletRequest`, how to put it into a model, how to change checkboxes' state according to date in the model, etc.

Comment: I am still did not able find a way to do this? Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
String[] checkeditems =request.getParameterValues("caseob");
```

To this line

```
String[] checkeditems =request.getParameterValues("case");
```

Because as you defined, your input name is "case" .

`<td><input id="cartcheckbox" class="case" type="checkbox" name="case"              value="${invoice}"/></td>`

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

Write a `javascript` which will trigger on `onclick` event of the `Confirm` button. In the `javascript` made a request for the `second.jsp`.